# Linguistics Greatest Hits

Tags: discussion

A new feature has been implemented: The [Greatest Hits](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/) page. You can view the [Linguistics Greatest Hits page here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits).

**What is this?** It's a page that features *"Questions that got a large amount of views or a large amount of feedback."* In other words, they are our *showcase*, the most important questions that received more feedback than other questions

**How are they calculated?** *"The current algorithm divides the number of page views with the total amount of question and answer feedback received (adding a bonus for high view counts), excluding questions with less views than the median:- 123."*

**What should we do with it?** Our mission from now on will be to improve these questions: fix typos, mistakes, check the links, edit the formatting, delete inappropriate content, vote to delete, flag, anything to improve the quality of these posts. This is very important because it would help us increase the appeal of our site and therefore bring more users to visit us and stay with us.

So when you have some free time and you're free-browsing  on the site, think about contributing. The order doesn't matter, you can edit randomly. :)

I forgot to add another thing: **Don't edit too many posts at once**. Editing will bump them to the front page (when you click the title of the site instead of the "New Questions" button), and will push off other questions; a handful will be enough. :)

Comment: Seven years ago, and I'd never heard of it, even though I'm very active on many SE sites.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I have been so long on this site never stumbling over that particular page. It needs some navigation path to be found, otherwise it is just useless.

Answer (score 2):

I've been going over the [Greatest Hits page](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/greatest-hits), and I'm kind of disappointed.

Three of these "greatest hits" are answered questions about syntax trees.  If we are willing to brag about these, why do we discourage questions about making trees? Just asking.

And one at least of them is loaded with really ignorant answers that give a poor impression of the professionalism here. I'll leave it up to you to decide which.

And I'm not even done yet. * *Sigh* *

Comment: Can you please VTC and/or flag so it appeared in Review Queue?

Comment: Who's bragging? Also questions in this category are simply the ones with the most feedback, not necessarily the ones of higher quality of content. Finally, any contribution is fine, even (self) criticism, but you can still give it without the condescending tone.